# Xcode debugger, I don't get this

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb, debugging

I am trying to understand how to accomplish some basic debugging stuff with gdb

I want to check the length of this control (UILabel)
if I type the following in the console I get nothing, what's the proper way to do it?

```
(gdb) po self.mylabel.frame.size.width
There is no member named frame.
```

or if I try without self:

```
(gdb) po mylabel.frame.size.width
There is no member named frame.
```

There must be a way, not obvious for sure. Visual Studio has such a fantastic debugger helpers in tracking the values of objects and co...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just type `po myLabel`, it will output the frame details. Of you can also use `po NSStringFromCGRect(myLabel.frame)`. (See this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) for some useful function along the lines of NSStringFromCGRect.)

Alternatively, width is a float, so you can use `p (float) myLabel.frame.size.width`.

In general, `po` is used to print the value of objects, while `p` is used for basic types.

Comment: thank you for the very helpful tip. - Any idea why self is not printing anything? It should be an object, right?

Comment: `po self` should work. Are you getting an error, or is it just doing nothing?

Comment: it tells me "no symbols in frame" - the code runs fine and does the job.

Comment: No idea. You might try asking in a new question.